# Karp-Rabin multiple pattern search without hashing

Tags: python, hash, rabin-karp

I'm having trouble using Karp-Rabin (without hashing)for multiple pattern search. Here's my example :

```
_string="today is a good day"

_patterns=['good', 'day']

def multiple_pattern_search(string,substrings,size):
    stringsize=string[:size]
    for i in range(len(stringsize)-size+1):
        if stringsize in substrings and string[:i+size-1] in substrings:
            return i
        stringsize=string[1:size+1]
    return 

print(multiple_pattern_search(_string,_sublist,3))
```

Output: `None`

Expected output: `2,16`

both of with correspond to the offset for 'day'

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS. Are there any python implementation of Karp-Rabin multiple pattern search with hashing?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
def multiple_pattern_search(string,substrings,size):
        matched=[]
        #stringsize=string[:size]
        for i in range(len(string)-size+1):
            stringsize=string[i:size+i]
            if stringsize not in substrings:
                substring=string[i:size+i]
            if stringsize in substrings:
                if string[i:size+i] in substrings:
                    matched.append(i)
        return matched

    print(multiple_pattern_search(_string,_patterns,3))

    Output: [2, 16]
```

while this solution may have worked, my main goal is to implement multiple pattern search using rolling hash. Your ideas will be appreciated.